The yield command will not work as it should in Ruby
In the book "The Well-Grounded Rubyist" edition 3 on page 185 is the code. And the code for my_each is on page 183. It also involve code on page 184:
Class Array
# Put the definition of my_each here
  def my_each
    c = 0
    until c == size
      yield self[c]
      c += 1
    end
    self
  end
# Here ends my_each
  def my_map
    acc = []
    my_each {|e| acc << yield e }
    acc
  end
end
# Code on page 184
names = ["David", "Alan", "Black"]
names.my_map {|name| name.upcase }
# Code on page 184 ends

I get this error message when I run it:
page185a.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting '}'
(SyntaxError)
my_each {|e| acc << yield e }

The ^ is under the last e on the line above.
I have tried to split up parts of the line on different
lines but I can't get it to work anyway. Even in another
program have I had problems with yield but I have solved
it by using other code. But this one have been hard for me to solve. I'm new to Ruby so I need to learn this. What's the same in both programs is the combination of << and yield.

The 2nd edition had parentheses in place, i.e. yield(self[c]) and my_each {|e| acc << yield(e) }. Wonder why they were stripped from the 3rd edition. However, the book's source code repository contains them: https://github.com/jleo3/twgr/tree/master/ch06

yield is a keyword and thus has a different specificity from normal method calls when used with other operators such as <<. In your case, Ruby parsed your my_map methods as follows:
def my_map
  acc = []
  my_each {|e| (acc << yield) e }
  acc
end

This can not work since e can not be an argument here. You can however avoid this issue by explicitly adding parentheses at the right spots to your yield call:
def my_map
  acc = []
  my_each {|e| acc << yield(e) }
  acc
end


acc << (yield e) also works, if you prefer.

Thank you very much. Both worked very well.
